# Online software to manipulate hypergraphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, math-software, hypergraphs

There are many software systems around working with graphs, but is there anything (preferably publically available / online) to handle hypergraphs? Thanks!

Comment: Check: http://hypergraph.sourceforge.net/ for one option.

Comment: @Fred Kline: despite the name, this site seems to have nothing to do with hypergraphs...